# WPF ListBox does not realise that its items have changed size

Tags: wpf, animation, user-controls, listbox, scrollbar

I have a `ListBox` that contains a number of `User` items that are `DataTemplate`d to appear as `UserControl`s in the `ListBox`. Each `UserControl` can be expanded in size. To start with, the `ListBox` is big enough to display them all in their unexpanded state. The problem that I have is that when a number of these `UserControl`s are expanded together, they extend out of the `ListBox`'s visible area. The `ListBox` does not recognise this fact and no `ScrollBar`s appear, even when they are set to `Visible`.

I am using `DoubleAnimation`s to alter the `UserControl` heights when the user clicks on a button in each one. Is there something that I have to do, or some setting on the `ListBox` that must be set to get it to register the size changes of the `UserControl`s that represent its items and display `ScrollBar`s when needed?

Edit>>>

I have tracked down the problem to a custom `WrapPanel` that I am using in the `ListBox.ItemsPanel`. When I remove it, or replace it with a standard `WrapPanel`, `ScrollBar`s appear when required. I got the code for the `Panel` from a good article about [creating custom WPF panels](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-creating-a-custom-panel-control). Can anyone see what's missing from the code given in the article and why it might stop the `ScrollBar`s from displaying?

Comment: Are you animating Height? In that case, I see no reason that your `ListBox` wouldn't adjust. You are not using RenderTransform, are you?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Can you add some sample code to your question?

Comment: I am applying a `TranslateTransform` on the `UIElement.RenderTransfrom` property of each of the `Panel.Children` in the `ArrangeOverride` method of the custom `WrapPanel`. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to write the custom `WrapPanel` code again completely and this time it worked correctly! When comparing the new version with the previous version, I could see that a + was missing from a += in a measuring calculation and so the `Panel` thought that the items were much smaller than they really were... hence no `ScrollBar`s.

So, if you have this problem, check your measuring code carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether ListBoxes normally do what you are expecting?  You might try calling InvalidateMeasure/Layout on the ListBox if you know when the item sizes change, just to see?

Comment: I tried adding a `Click` handler to the edit `Button` and calling `listBox.Invalidate...()` and `listBox.UpdateLayout()` but that had no effect. Please see my updated post for more information.